# Uploading or linking to pictures to a Page from the Facebook Android feed dialog

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an Android app with a requirement to upload a picture from the Android device to a Page that the user has Liked, using the Feed dialog.  (The user is not an administrator of the Page.)  I have not been able to get this to work in a way that actually displays the picture on the Page's timeline.  I am going to describe what I have done, what happens, and what I would like to see; hopefully someone can help me out.

Here is the sequence of events that happens right now:

1. Within the app, the user connects to Facebook using the Login button provided by the Android SDK.
2. The user takes a picture using the app which is stored on the local device.
3. The app uploads the picture to one of the user's Facebook albums.
4. The app constructs a URL that points to the picture in the user's album.
5. The app invokes the Feed dialog with these parameters.  "pictureUrl" is the URL that was built in step 4; "pageFbId" is the internal Facebook ID of the Page on which the picture should appear.

   ```
   Bundle params = new Bundle();
   params.putString("link", pictureUrl);
   params.putString("to", pageFbId);
   ```
6. The user completes the entry in the Feed dialog.
7. The page's timeline shows the text entered by the user in the Feed dialog and a link to the picture in the user's album.

Is there a way to do this so that Facebook actually shows the picture on the Page's timeline, instead of just a link to the picture?

Thanks!

Comment: You could add a step in there to query the picture url in the graph api and use the image parameter to add it to post.

Comment: @Shawn, I will give that a shot, thanks! ... I don't see the "image" parameter in the documentation for the feed dialog (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed), is that undocumented or did I just miss it somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

**Example:**  Setting picture parameter in Facebook Feed dialog via JS SDK.

*IOS, Adroid examples to come.*

---

```
<script> 
    function feedthis() {
    var obj = {
    method: 'feed',
    link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
    picture: 'https://developers.facebook.com/images/devsite/developers_og_image.png',
    name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
    caption: 'Reference Documentation',
    description: 'Test via spoof Post',
        properties: [
        { text: 'Link Test 1', href: 'http://example.com'},
          { text: 'Link Test 2', href: 'http://example.com?ref=1'},
        ],
        actions: [
        { name: 'via Test App', link: 'http://anotherfeed.com'}
        ]
};
function callback(response) { // get post id here from response object.}
FB.ui(obj, callback);
}
</script>
```

Comment: I gave this a shot, but the picture parameter only works to get an image in the post on the Page if the image is from outside of the facebook.com domain.  If I try to use the URL to the picture posted to the user's photo album, I get a message about the feed dialog not allowing pictures from the FBCDN.  Other than hosting the user's photos on a different non-Facebook server, is there any way around that, so that I can show the user's photo on the Page's timeline?